# Fourier with 2D data

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I have a set of points (x1,y1)......(xn,yn) that represent for example readings from a laser range finder of a certain obstacle. Using these points I want to draw the approximated shape.

As I understood and also which I implemented that if I have a function I can represent an approximation using Fourier. How can I achieve that using Mathematica?

Comment: What are you trying to `Fourier` transform? If you want to visualize a shape, you're going to want to use `Polygon` and `Graphics`

Comment: I want to draw the approximated shape using these points

Comment: `Polygon[pts]//Graphics`?

Comment: it is a Polygon[pts]

Comment: Mohamed, frankly what you are asking makes no sense to me as written. I do not understand what it would mean to take the Fourier transform of a polygon. Could you describe your problem in more detail, ideally WITH SOME CODE, so we can at least understand what you need?

Comment: Sorry for this misunderstanding,  I mean if I have a set of points which represent for example reading from a laser range finder of a certain obstacle, and by using these points I want to draw the approximated shape. As I understood and also which I implemented that if I have a function I can represent an approximation using Fourier.

Comment: @MohamedAbdallahMohamed ooooh you want to fit your data to an expansion in `Sin` and `Cos`? That makes sense to me

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to ask how to fit to a Fourier series (i.e. a series in `Cos[n*x]` and `Sin[n*x]`)? If so here's an example using `LinearModelFit` and fitting to a `Cos` series with some fake data supplied

```
grid = Range[-π, π, .01];
fakeData = RandomReal[{}, Length[grid]] + Cos[5*grid];

fourierFit =
  LinearModelFit[
   Transpose@{grid, fakeData},
   Table[Cos[i*x], {i, 0, 5}],
   x
   ];
```

and here's how the fit looks like against the data it came from

```
Show[
 ListPlot[Transpose@{grid, fakeData}],
 Plot[fourierFit["BestFit"], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a rectangular array of distances, it sounds to me like you just want to show what the surface looks like. If that’s the case, maybe try `ListPointPlot3D[data]` or `ListPlot3D[data]` if you want a continuous surface. You may also need to add the option `PlotRange -> Full` depending on what your data looks like.

```
data = Table[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5, 0.01}, {y, -5, 5, 0.01}];
ListPointPlot3D[data[[;; ;; 10, ;; ;; 10]], PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
ListPlot3D[data, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image: ListPointPlot3D of sample data.]

[image: ListPlot3D of sample data.]

I generate a ton of points here to make the `ListPlot3D` look nice, but it ends up being a bit much for `ListPointPlot3D` so I reduce the number of points for that one. You can also add colour to represent the distance of the points if you're trying to replicate the usual LIDAR point cloud:

```
ListPointPlot3D[
  data[[;; ;; 10, ;; ;; 10]], 
  Background -> Black
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][#3] &), 
  PlotRange -> {-3, 3}
]
ListPlot3D[
  data, 
  ColorFunction -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][#3] &),
  PlotRange -> {-3, 3}
]
```

[image: ListPointPlot3D of sample data with colour.]

[image: ListPlot3D of sample data with colour.]

It seems like a lot of us are a bit confused as to what exactly you want to do, however. So my answer is probably wrong, but you might want to think about adding some more details to your question. I think I understand what the input is (an m x n array of distances), but what kind of output should there be?